An "almost" geodesic dome
A regular $ n$-gon is inscribed in the unit circle centered in $0$.
We want to build an "almost" geodesic dome upon it this way: on each side of the $n$-gon we build an equilateral triangle whose dihedral angle with the $n$-gon is such that the distance from $0$ of the upper vertex's projection on the unit circle plane is $(1-1/n)$; over this "first floor" we connect all the upper vertices and we have a new smaller $n$-gon inscribed in the circle with radius $(1-1/n)$, so we repeat the process and this time the distance from $0$ of the upper vertices' projection on the unit circle plane is $(1-2/n)$ and so on.
If the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$, which function fits the border of the dome? What is the maximum height?
I tried to solve this way: $n$ fixed and $r < n$, each upper vertex coordinate is
$ ( \dfrac {r+1}{n}, \sum_{m=0}^r\sqrt{( \sqrt{3}(1-\dfrac m{n}) \sin(\dfrac \pi{n}) )^2-\dfrac1{n^2}} )$
With $n = 100 $ this is the plot made with Mathematica, but I wasn't able to find that function


If I understand the construction (I may not), the dome fails to close when $n>7$, because the equilateral triangles become too small to span required distances. Consider just the inner/top-most $n$-gon, of radius $r=1/n$, whose triangles "should" meet above the center. However, one readily shows that equilateral triangles on the $n$-gon's sides cannot even reach the center if $n$ exceeds $6$. (When $n=6$, they just make it, creating a flat hexagonal roof.) Likewise, there are bounds on $n$ to build each other ring of triangles. ... Am I missing something? Is closing not a requirement?

@Blue yes exactly, closing is not a requirement, if it's not possible to close, the construction just stop and we have a "roof"

When $\frac{r+1}n=x$ and $n$ tends to the infinity then $n^2\sin^2\frac{\pi}n$ tends to $\pi^2$, and it can be shown that the second upper vertex coordinate tends to an integral sum for the integral $\int_0^x \sqrt{3\pi^2(1-t)^4-1}\, dt$, and so the coordinate tends to the value of the integral, which are shown at the following graph.

Unfortunately, the integral is elliptic, and these integrals, in general, cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, see the Wikipedia article for details.

thank you for your reply, there is an error in the expression I wrote.  The correct answer is given here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/473011/an-almost-geodesic-dome
